# optimization or nonlinear optimal control solver?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, discrete-optimization

I am looking for some solvers on "optimization or nonlinear optimal control(along with constraints)". Could you recommend me some solver candidates?

Best Regards

Jie

Comment: Maybe you can write your own. How hard can it be?

Answer (score 0):

If it's convex optimization, then you can use [Yalmip](https://yalmip.github.io/) (interface for specifying the optimization problem) and the solvers [Mosek](https://www.mosek.com/), [SeDuMi](https://sedumi.ie.lehigh.edu/), or other solvers. You can check out the list of Yalmip's [solvers](https://yalmip.github.io/solver/mosek/).